# VBA Setting Chart Source Data with Variables?

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to set source data using two sections of data for a chart using variables. When I use just one of the variables it selects the right area for the respective variable. However, when I put both in it causes one of the selections to be different (Larger). Is there a way to do it so it selects both areas as if I was selecting them individually.

Here is the code with both the variables.

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range( _
 X, Y)
```

Comment: What ranges do `X` and `Y` represent? Be careful when using ranges within a `Range` call: for example, note that `Range("A1:A10,C1:C10")` is different than `Range("A1:A10","C1:C10")`. The latter includes `B1:B10`, the former does not.

Comment: Thanks so much, got it.